# Unable to complete Cyanogenmod 14 setup

Tags: cyanogenmod, setup-wizard

Hei, I Just installed CM14 on my Nexus 6p + Gapps. 
All clean, fresh unlocked etc.
Cyanogen boots up to setup-wizard the device, select the language etc.
But after the wifi selection the "tranfer data from another device" opens up and I can not cancel it / proceed it. 
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I changed 3 times the language and got back of the screen .
Then an crash report came up and I langed on the "complete setup" screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now the Setup Wizard is known to be broken across [multiple](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-mi-3/development/rom-cm14-xiaomi-mi3-t3459414/page2) [devices](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/development/rom-cyanogenmod-14-0-t3470615/page31) on CM14.x.

The solution for now seems to be removing `/system/priv-app/CyanogenSetupWizard` from your recovery. But the trick is that you shouldn't just delete it; instead, move the folder elsewhere for backup, then boot up into the OS properly. You will notice things like the notification bar and recent keys working weird. Don't worry - boot into recovery again and place that folder back to where it was, and set correct permissions (rwxr-xr-x for folder, rw-r--r-- for file). Reboot and you should see the Setup Wizard briefly come up but goes away if you interact with it. That's it - now start using the phone as you would normally.